# Executing code on creation in scala trait subclass

Tags: scala, traits

I'd like to define a `val` in a `trait` that gets computed once by sub-class that gets instantiated.

For instance :

```
trait Example
{
    val p : Int
    val after : Int = p + 1
}

class Ex(x : Int) extends Example
{
    val p = x
}
```

I want `after` to be computed for each instance of Ex, but no matter which parameter `x` I give, `after` is always `1`. As if, `p` was `0` for the computation.

Of course, it works with def, but then it is no longer computed only once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`after` in `Example` is instantiated right away, before your `Ex` actually is instantiated - and then before even looking at your `x`.

To fix it you can turn `after` into a `lazy val`, it will be evaluated the first time you use it.

Comment: The non-lazy syntax in the other answer is more obvious.

Answer (score 2):

First of all a `val` variable is immutable, so it can only be assigned once. So it would not be possible to do `p = x`. But when you do `val p = x` in the `Ex` class you are assigning other variable that you just defined, so `after` would not change.

You have to define the abstract variable `var p` in your `Ex` class, so it will be able to set the `val p` defined in `Example`. For example, define the `var p` in the constructor as below.

```
trait Example
{
    val p : Int
    val after : Int = p + 1
}

class Ex(val p : Int) extends Example
```

Demo

```
scala> val ex = new Ex(5)
ex: Ex = Ex@1f7ebc89

scala> ex.p
res4: Int = 5

scala> ex.after
res5: Int = 6
```

Comment: I don't understand the first part about "when you do `val p = x`". Member `Ex.p` is overriding `p` in both the OP and your example.  The difference is that the field is initialized early (before super ctors) for the class param.